# Kestrel fails to bind port after server restart

Tags: c#, linux, sockets, ubuntu, asp.net-core

#### Good day.

I have a problem with ASP.NET Core WebAPI server. It occurs ~80% of the time when I restart the web server.
It **DOES NOT** happen on any local Windows machine.

#### Technical details:

Server is ran on Ubuntu Linux:

```sh
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="16.04.6 LTS (Xenial Xerus)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS"
VERSION_ID="16.04"
HOME_URL="http://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="http://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
VERSION_CODENAME=xenial
UBUNTU_CODENAME=xenial
```

Dotnet information:

```sh
~# dotnet --version
2.2.203

~# dotnet --list-sdks
2.0.3 [/usr/share/dotnet/sdk]
2.1.4 [/usr/share/dotnet/sdk]
2.2.203 [/usr/share/dotnet/sdk]
```

Server itself built for .NET Core 2.0

#### Problem that occurs:

Kestrel fails to bind port after server restart. I'm binding it at 2001 port.

#### Logs from `journalctl`:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.IO.IOException: Failed to bind to address http://[::]:2001: address already in use. ---> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Connections.AddressInUseException: Address already in use ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: Address already in use
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.UpdateStatusAfterSocketErrorAndThrowException(SocketError error, String callerName)
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoBind(EndPoint endPointSnapshot, SocketAddress socketAddress)
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Bind(EndPoint localEP)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Sockets.SocketTransport.BindAsync()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
```

#### How do I resolve it:

I can't really do anything about it. I have to wait for a few minutes (it will restart and crash a few times) and then the server will start correctly like nothing ever happened.

#### What I've tried:

I created a small code that tries to bind port before starting Kestrel.
If it fails it waits a bit then tries again. Basically it waits until port will be freed.
When bind is successful it frees port and tries to start Kestrel.
This code worked perfectly on my machine but doesn't work on remote Linux machine.

My best guess is that it's something related to IPv6 but I really have no clue what exactly.

(Kestrel restarts perfectly on Windows (with IPv4 addresses in local network) and fails on Linux (with IPv6 local address))

#### I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: What I would do from client is to run ping from cmd.exe >ping -t IP.  The -t option runs ping continuously.  Then restart the server a few times and see how long it takes for the ping to start working.  Try on both window and linux.  I'm not sure if it is the server taking a long time to start recognizing IP, or there is an existing connection that is not closing and eventually timing out.

Comment: After stopping the server, you probably have a connection in TIME_WAIT state. This is to handle packets that may still be travelling in the network. Different OSs have different implementations how to restrict using the same port number. Linux is more restrictive than Windows. To re-use the same port you would have to set socket option SO_REUSEADDR and/or SO_REUSEPORT before calling `bind` in the server code. (I don#t know how to do this in C#.) see http://www.serverframework.com/asynchronousevents/2011/01/time-wait-and-its-design-implications-for-protocols-and-scalable-servers.html

Comment: @jdweng Ping doesn't do anything related to port being opened or closed.

Comment: @Bodo will check, thanks!

Comment: You cannot open a port nor close unless PING works.  So PING has everything to do with ports being open or closed.  If you do not have a route to the server than ping will not work and the open/close will not work.

Comment: It heavily depends on how you registered the application to launch, as only after the network stack is initialized fully it can bind to the interface and handle traffic. Only Windows, IIS only starts after such initialization (Windows service dependency guarantees that), so you won't easily hit such, but on Linux you need to be caution.

Comment: @Vyacheslav There might be some misunderstanding about your question. I interpreted "server restart" as a restart of the Kestrel web server. Others seem to understand it as a restart of the computer. You should make clear in your question what you mean. What is the difference between your machine and the remote Linux machine? If you cannot modify the relevant Kestrel code and want to use your workaround you should show the source code of your "small code that tries to bind port..."

Comment: I mean the restart of the server, not computer. @Bodo

Comment: @Bodo also this small code was removed a few weeks ago. It's simply tries to bind TCP listener and then dispose it if bind was successful.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to add clarification or requested information instead of answering in comments. All relevant information should be **in the question**. It doesn't help if you repeat or slightly reword the information that is already present in the question. I suggest to clarify **in the question** that the word "server" refers to the **Kestrel web server**, not to the computer. I suggest to change the question title accordingly. If you describe the code instead of showing it, we cannot help you finding possible problems with it.

Comment: @Bodo Already clarified it. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Force Kill Method:

If you want to find what's attached to the port, on ubuntu use:

```
lsof -i :2001
```

It will display both IPv4 and IPv6.   Look for "LISTEN"

Once you've confirmed you don't care what's listening there previously, you can forcefully clear out the port as part of your pre-start routine.

```
lsof -ti :2001 | xargs --no-run-if-empty kill -9
```

Comment: Seems like server wasn't stopping due to an infinite thread. This helped me. Thank you.